# Как реализовать множ. выбор match по введенному числу?

Tags: rust, match

Решил попробовать rust. Не могу понять как реализовать множ.выбор `match` по введенному числу. *VSCode* подсвечивает красным цифры. Смотрел примеры в интернете, но ничего не нашел для моей задачи.

```
 let mut mnum: i32;
 let mut mnum = String::new();
 io::stdin().read_line(&mut mnum).expect("err");

 match mnum {
      1 => func::messages::message_functions::hello(),
      2 => func::messages::message_functions::work(),
      3  => func::messages::message_functions::bye(),
      4 => test1::Func::test(),
   _=> panic!(),
    
 }
```

/**Новая версия, запустилась, но проблемы с логикой не вызывает функции  */

```
let mut mnum = String::new();  
let mnum = io::stdin().read_line(&mut mnum).expect("err");
   match &mnum {
   
      1 => func::messages::message_functions:::hello(),
      2 => func::messages::message_functions::work(),
      3 => func::messages::message_functions::bye(),
      4 => test1::Func::test(),
  _ => {
        panic!("Ошибка: ");
      
    }
 }
```

после ввода выдает ошибку. непонятно, что не так. Эта простая задача для других языков. Если переменную инициализировать в коде то при запуске все работает. Пример рабочего кода:

```
 let mut mnum = String::new();
 let mut mnum: i32 = 1;

 match mnum {
      1 => func::messages::message_functions::hello(),
      2 => func::messages::message_functions::work(),
      3  => func::messages::message_functions::bye(),
      4 => test1::Func::test(),
   _=> panic!(),
    
 }
```

Нужно чтобы число вводилось (т.е.выбор меню и вызов функции из тела match) с командной строки.

Comment: А это что такое: `let mut mnum = String::new();` - это же строка, а не число? Я `Rust` вообще не знаю, но выглядит странно, что у вас сначала переменная определяется как целая, а потом в неё кладётся строка. Поэтому что в эту переменную читается через `read_line` число или строка я вообще теряюсь в догадках. Возможно, у вас подсвечивается, что вы строку пытаетесь сравнивать с числами.

Comment: Пример со считыванием числа есть прям сразу же во второй главе книги... https://doc.rust-lang.ru/book/ch02-00-guessing-game-tutorial.html

Comment: получилось запустить код после правки: let mut mnum = String::new();  
    let mnum = io::stdin().read_line(&mut mnum).expect("Failed to read line");
     match &mnum { , но методы из модулей не вызываются. если явно инициализировать переменную в строке кода код работает нормально. Вывод такой что то неправильно при вводе.

Comment: Функция `read_line` возвращает количество прочитанных байтов, и вы сохранили это количество в переменную `mnum`, тем самым уничтожив прочитанную строку. Кроме того, важно не забывать, что она считывает символ переноса строки. Это означает, что для того, чтобы сработал match 1, вам нужно ввести ничего (просто нажать Enter, чтобы ввёлся 1 символ переноса строки), чтобы сработал match 2 — ввести один символ, чтобы сработал match 4 — ввести три символа (например `foo` и затем четвёртый Enter) и так далее по аналогии

Comment: Я всё-таки предполагаю, что вам просто не хватает преобразования `mnum` из строки в число. Ну либо в `match` пишите не просто числа, а числа в виде строк. А так то видимо в `read_line` передаётся **ссылка** на `mnum`, поэтому там уже будет значение, не нужно потом никуда ничего присваивать.

Comment: И вы бы показали скриншот, как именно подсвечивает у вас, с какой ошибкой или что. Может там прямо так и написано, что вы сравниваете строку с числами и это сравнение никогда не сработает.

Comment: @CrazyElf прямо так и пишет ```mismatched types: expected `String`, found integer``` (но видимо автору до сих пор лень прочитать вторую главу книги, там даже прямым текстом упоминается и разбирается эта ошибка)

Comment: @andreymal С книжками не интересно, с книжками любой может! ))

Comment: Да читал, понятно что mismatched types.. я только вчера сел за rust думал в match сделать как в си switch но так и ненашел  подходящей функции.

Comment: @U255 а нужно было думать, как преобразовать строку в число (и пример этого есть во всё той же второй главе книги)

Comment: @U255 Да ни в одном языке не сматчится строка с числом, от языка это вообще не зависит. Только преобразовывать к одному типу.

Answer (score 1):

разобрался надо еще один match с приведением в число:

```
let mut mnum = String::new(); 
io::stdin().read_line(&mut mnum).expect("err");

let mnum:u32 = match mnum.trim().parse() {
  Ok(mnum) => mnum,
  Err(_) => panic!()
};

 match mnum {
    1 => func::messages::message_functions::hello(),
    2 => func::messages::message_functions::work(),
    3  => func::messages::message_functions::bye(),
    4 => test1::Func::test(),
  _=> panic!(), 

 }
```

Comment: Вместо первого match можно сделать let mnum: u32 = mnum.trim().parse().unwrap(); будет то же самое.